# Link to nested resource loses active class after page reload

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm learning ember these days and I encountered a problem with link-to helper. If I use it to create a link for nested route it works fine (if click on the link, "active" class will be added to the element - as described in docs) until I reload the page. When I reload the page the content for nested rouse will be loaded to the {{outlet}} properly but link will lose its "active" class. What am I doing wrong?

JavaScript:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({ rootElement: '#app' });

App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('notes', { path: '/' }, function () {
    this.route('show', { path: '/:note_id' });
  });
});

App.NotesRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return App.Note.find();
  }
});

App.NotesShowRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return App.Note.find(params.note_id);
  }
});

App.Note = Em.Object.extend();

App.Note.reopenClass({
  find: function(id) {
    var notes = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'abc',
        text: 'lorem ipsum text 1111111'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'def',
        text: 'lorem ipsum text 2222222'
      }
    ];
    return id ? notes[parseInt(id) - 1] : notes;
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app" class="row">
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <h2>Tags</h2>
      </div>
      {{outlet}}
    </script>
</div>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="notes">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h2>Notes</h2>
    {{#each}}
      {{#link-to 'notes.show' this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}
    {{/each}}
    </div>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="notes/show">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <h2>{{title}}</h2>
      <p>{{text}}</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click a link-to, it passes the object to the new route. So the model lookup isn't called. So both the context of the show route and the linked object refer to the same object. So it will get marked as active.

However, when you refresh the page, you're doing the lookup twice, once in the NotesRoute model (which you loop over with each), and once in the NotesShowRoute model.

Javascript objects are reference types. Two plain javascript objects aren't considered equal, even if their content is the same. e.g. try typing this into your javascript console.

```
{ one: 1, two: 2} == {one: 1, two: 2}
```

So the object referred to in the link-to isn't the same as the model of the current route. So the equality check for the link being active won't work.

Quick solution is to stop the find from creating the object every time. e.g.

```
App.Note.reopenClass({
  all: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'abc',
      text: 'lorem ipsum text 1111111'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'def',
      text: 'lorem ipsum text 2222222'
    }
  ],
  find: function(id) {
    return id ? this.all[parseInt(id) - 1] : this.all;
  }
});
```

Another options is to roll some sort of identity map for your objects. [Here is a blog post](http://balinterdi.com/2013/12/03/roll-your-own-ember-dot-js-identity-map.html) doing a much better example than I can of explaining it.

Note I haven't actually tested that code because I'm too lazy to create a jsbin. But let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: I've just tested the code and can confirm it works perfectly fine. I wasn't aware at all that the problem is in the model not in the router / template.  Thank you very much for your help!